# Yarn no importa scripts ni jQuery

Tags: javascript, symfony, yarn

Estoy intentando integrar unos scripts que tengo en mi proyecto de symfony, tengo instalado Yarn para ello donde tengo la siguiente configuración:

`webpack.config.js`

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Por otra parte este es mi `app.js` que es el que importa los scripts:

```
import '../css/app.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
var $ = require( "jquery" );
import './scripts.js';
```

Los estilos dep app.css sí que me los coge bien, pero los scripts no.